# removing duplicates in array of arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of arrays, like this:

```
aa = [ [a,d], [a,d1], [a,d], [b,d], [b,d2], [b,d3], [b,d2], [a,d2] ]
```

I would like to have a unique array of arrays, not just on the first element - which I can do by doing something like aa.uniq(&:first) - but rather remove the inner arrays if BOTH values match.  So the result would be:

```
aa = [ [a,d], [a,d1], [a,d2], [b,d], [b,d2], [b,d3] ]
```

Can anyone assist in pointing me to an efficient way of doing this?  I have large nr of arrays - in the order of 1 million - that I need to process.

Any help appreciated! John

Comment: what do you mean by `aa.uniq(&:first)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to maintain a collection of elements **where each element is unique and their order is not important**. You should use a [Set](http://apidock.com/ruby/Set). For instance,

```
require 'set'
my_set = Set.new
my_set << [1, 'a']
my_set << [1, 'a']
my_set << [1, 'b']
my_set.each { |elem| puts "#{elem}" }
```

It will give you

```
[1, "a"]
[1, "b"]
```

**If the order is important**, then use the `uniq!` on you array

```
aa.uniq!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
aa = [ ["a","d"], ["a","d1"], ["a","d"], ["b","d"] ]
aa.uniq
aa=[["a", "d"], ["a", "d1"], ["b", "d"]]
```

You missed double quotations ("). Inside of array, variables a, d, a, d1, etc. are strings. So, you should put them inside of double quotations ("").

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get unique elements from an array, which will remove duplicate element, you can try this:

```
a = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
a & a #=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```